# Unable to update PowerGUI Script editor to latest version

Tags: powershell, powergui

**OS:** Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64.

At some point I figured I can no longer update my IDE for Powershell - PowerGUI Script Editor (latest is v3.7.0.92 at the moment of writing). I am getting this error when inside the script editor -> check for updates, as well as in a standalone installation, in both cases the installation is rolled back.

[image]

In my Programs and Features I have the following relevant entries:

- (A) Quest PowerGUI 3.6 --- Version 3.6.0.21
- (B) Quest PowerGUI 3.6 --- Version 3.6.0.8

When I attempt to uninstall (A), I am getting this error:

[image]

Although the current version inside the script editor is shown as **3.6.0.21**.

And when trying to uninstall (B), I get a standard Modify/Repair/Remove dialog, but when I do *Remove*, it ends up with the first error again (#1722 above). Doing *Repair* works, but does not solve the problem, i.e. still **unable to Update**.

Is there any way I can make it work again?

P.S. One may point out this to be part of superuser, yet I think it's an inherent part of Powershell development and so deserves a place on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the uninstall function either doesn't complete correctly or misses some important registry settings. I had the same problem, and this resolved it for me:

1. download and run the <kbd>[microsoft uninstall utility](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)</kbd>
2. in the utility do the following:

   1. select the **install or upgrade software or hardware** category.
   2. find and run the **fix problems with programs that can't be installed or uninstalled**.
   3. give answers to the prompts regarding the powergui instance that will not uninstall.
   4. exit the utility.
3. install the powergui version of your choice.
4. get pint from pub

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to install new PowerGUI, which is now working fine. I still have a ghost of PowerGUI in Programs and Features, version 3.6.0.8, attempting to uninstall that shows the above error. But the current installed version is, well, current. +1 and accepting.

Comment: I also have that same ghost 3.6.0.8 but if it's working now then I'm happy